# Can I put some array as a field in a java class and access it using native method?

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface

Can I put some array as a field in a java class that implements java `iterator`, then iterating over it using `next()`. and will the java `GC` deallocate it after the object of that class goes out of scope?

The objects of the mentioned class will be constructed on the rust-side but `next` method will call some native method which will retrieve the next element in the array.